# Best way to get right n digits from number in SQL Server (CE)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a sql server compact framework database and I want to query an int column

the column can contain values from 1 to 99999999 and I am interested in the right 4 digits

Examples:

```
     1 ->    1
    12 ->   12
   123 ->  123
  1234 -> 1234
 12345 -> 2345
123456 -> 3456
```

I could convert the result to string and use substring, but there is propably a better solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [Modulo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx)

```
 select 123456 % 10000
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24560)

Answer (score 4):

If you

```
SELECT WhateverField % 10000
```

you will get the 4 rightmost digits.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT RIGHT(column_name, n)
```

-- n is number of `digits`

Comment: You can also do LEFT() in the same way.

Comment: This will still convert the result to string and use substring, which is what OP wanted to avoid. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: @RoyDictus : ye but it give same results ?

Comment: @Vijaykumar Hadalgi - This fails for SQL Server compact . It would also involve cast and `number % 10000` is way better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Mod 10 for getting the last digit of any number.

Example : `12345%10 = 5`

so if you want to get n number of last digits u n number of zeros :

example : if you want last 4 digits use 4 zero's after 1

Sql command: `select column% 10000;`

ex: `123456-> 123456/10000 = 3456`

you can use Division by 10 for getting the first Digits.